App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher
Google Notice for my app 
image Proof
My App bundle which was published on june 6
Why am i getting the notice from google that my app doesnot meet the android api level even though we can see in the image that the app targets API 34
and the i got the message from google on july 1 which is around 1 month after the app is published.
here is the part of build.gradle just to make sure
android {
namespace "xxx"
compileSdkVersion 34
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
   
........

}
I have tried trying to make the minsdk to 34 but that resulted in having device limitations and all so i dont think i was supposed to change the minsdk so i didnt try to publish it

My guess would be that the notice is for some other app bundle that you have published earlier (maybe in an alpha or beta test track).

i checked after your comment and found out that in open testing i had a release which targeted api 33 , that may be the reason i am getting, is there a way to delete the testing releases i tried to search for that but didnt find any solution so i have just uploaded the release form the app library that targeted api 34 (open testing)in the hopes that this fixes it

Just pause/close the test track, you will not be noticed anymore @EDAPTECHNOLOGY

You don't need to update a min SDK version, please verify on your end that you have uploaded the correct bundle on play store,
If you still think it's correct, then either you can submit a request to the google play store team or upload a new version on the play store.

Thanks for help everyone i found out the problem was in my testing releases as it had bundles that were targeted for api 33 , i had paused the track and seemed to do the trick for me
